# Show status bar android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created a new activity but the `status bar` is hidden, I want to show

Here is my `activity` code

```
    class TurnsActivity : ToolbarActivity() {

    val fragmentAdapter = PageAdapterTurns(supportFragmentManager)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_turns)
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN)

        toolbarToLoad(toolbar as Toolbar)

        view_pager.adapter = fragmentAdapter

        tab.setupWithViewPager(view_pager)
        tab.getTabAt(0)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_sun)
        tab.getTabAt(1)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_moon)
    }
}
```

but activty is:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the style.xml clean? or you add a custom settings?

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two lines from `onCreate()`:

```
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN)
```

Check your `res -> values -> styles.xml` and Remove any line in your AppTheme that refers to StatusBar:

A normal AppTheme looks like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml` and remove any theme applied to your Activity

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity">
 ...
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

**delete these codes**

window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN)

Answer (score 0):

solved, status bar color was white instead hidden so I changed it

```
window.statusBarColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorAccent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun Activity.showStatusBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
        window.insetsController?.show(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
            (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE)
    }
}
```